# sending input to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come from Grails and I'm new with Ruby-on-Rails.

So, I learned that when you create a form_for with a symbol like :user("key"), when submited the params[] receive a new key with ":user" and the respective value from it:

```
<% form_for :user do |form| %>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Password</legend>

      <label for="current_password"> Current password:</label>
      <%= form.password_field :current_password %>
      <br>

      <label for="password"> New password:</label>
      <%= form.password_field :password %>
      <br>

      <label for="password_confirmation"> Confirm password:</label>
      <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      <br>
    </fieldset>
    <%= submit_tag "Update", :class => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

params[:user => {:current_password => 123 , :password => 321 , :password_confirmation => 321}], right?

Well, the problem is that Rails don't understand the :current_password and :password_confirmation , I don't know if the problem is about the Model User don't have those attributes, only name, password and email.

Error: undefined method `password_confirmation=' for #

Is there another way to fix it without creating a attr_accessor for both symbols? I just wanna work with a simple key inside the action like:

```
if params[:user].password = params[:user].password_confirmation

 do something...
```

Comment: In the Rails most popular book they use attr_accessor for the password confirmation. Anyway you can always delete that keys from the hash before passing it to the one of the model update methods.

Answer (score 1):

**params** is the Hash class. Actually it's not simple Hash class, it's [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://apidock.com/rails/HashWithIndifferentAccess), which adds possible to access to hash using string and symbol at one time.

What you need is understand http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html and also read some examples at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

In your example you also using assignment **=**, not the equal **==** sign. It's better to read some manuals about ruby before you start to dig in the rails world.

So fixing your error should look like:

```
if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
```

**Authlogic** or **Devise** gems do it by themself's. Don't reinvent the wheel before you find that you know all the alternatives and stuck behind the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The params are nested in a hash.  So, you'd access it like this:

```
if params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation]
  # do stuff
end
```